How to add watermark to an image through cloudinary in node.js
I want to use cloudinary to add watermark to the image i want to upload in node.js, here is an example of what it looks like ;
const transformationString = text:arial_20_bold:Location-${location}, Date-${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}, Time-${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()};
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(studentImage.tempFilePath, {
        folder: 'Image-Upload', 
        overwrite: true,
        tags: ['location', 'time', 'date'],
        transformation: [
            { width: 500, height: 500, crop: 'fill' }, // Resize the image
            { overlay: transformationString, gravity: 'south_east', color: 'white', opacity: 80, width: 400 }
        ]
    })

but it's showing this error "Invalid transformation component -  Date-4"

That's because you separate chained transformations using a comma, and Cloudinary interprets that as a different transformation.
Or you can escape the comma, read this: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202521512-How-to-add-a-special-characters-in-text-overlays
Or you can remove the comma before Date and Time like that:
text:arial_20_bold:Location-${location} Date-${new Date().toLocaleDateString()} Time-${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}
